# Access 2013 Query Error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to run what I believe is a pretty basic query. I am just attempting to calculate the number of payments received based on an aggregate total. However when I build the expression and try to run the query I get the error message:

> Your query does not include the specified expression 'Client_ID' as part of an aggregate function.

I have read several questions about this error but I cannot figure out what I am missing in my query, that is causing the same error. Here is my query:

```
SELECT Client.Client_Id, Loan.Loan_Id, ([Loan]![BalanceForward]+Sum([Payment]![Amount]))/[Loan]![PaymentAmount] AS [Payment Number]
FROM (Client LEFT JOIN Loan ON Client.Client_Id = Loan.Client_Id) LEFT JOIN Payment ON Loan.Loan_Id = Payment.Loan_Id
WHERE (((Client.Client_Id)=6));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you are missing a [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause. In aggregate SQL queries used to summarize a recordset, any fields not being aggregated with `Sum(), Count(), Avg(), Var(), Min(), Max()`... must be referenced in `GROUP BY`. Basically, it means you are summing or counting records, grouped by such and such fields (here, Client and Loan IDs).

```
SELECT Client.Client_Id, Loan.Loan_Id, 
    ([Loan]![BalanceForward] +
    DSum("Amount", "Payment", "Loan_Id=" & Payment.Loan_Id))/
    [Loan]![PaymentAmount] AS [Payment Number]
FROM (Client LEFT JOIN Loan ON Client.Client_Id = Loan.Client_Id) 
LEFT JOIN Payment ON Loan.Loan_Id = Payment.Loan_Id
WHERE (((Client.Client_Id)=6))
GROUP BY Client.Client_Id, Loan.Loan_Id,
        ([Loan]![BalanceForward] +
        DSum("Amount", "Payment", "Loan_Id=" & Payment.Loan_Id))/
        [Loan]![PaymentAmount];
```

However, you cannot combine a level field (i.e., Loan!BalanceForward, Loan!PaymentAmount) with an aggregated field (i.e., Payment!Amount) in same expression. Therefore, you will have to use the [Domain Aggregates](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/) (DSum, DLookUp, DAvg, DCount, and others). Alternatively, these same functions can be re-written with [subqueries](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/nested-subqueries.php).

Comment: Parfait - I was attempting to create Payment Number as a new field within the query. Can I not create a field within the query this way?

Comment: I have made the update you suggested and get the exact same error message as before, only now it references my expression.

Comment: Your query does not include the specified expression '([Loan]![BalanceForward]+Sum([Payment]![Amount]))/[Loan]![PaymentAmount]' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: The only way I have been able to get rid of this error message is to update my query as follows:

Comment: SELECT Client.Client_Id, Loan.Loan_Id, (([Loan]![CarriedForwardPayments]+Sum([Payment]![Amount]))/[Loan]![PaymentAmount]) AS [Payment Number]
FROM (Client LEFT JOIN Loan ON Client.Client_Id = Loan.Client_Id) LEFT JOIN Payment ON Loan.Loan_Id = Payment.Loan_Id
WHERE (((Client.Client_Id)=6))
GROUP BY Client.Client_Id, Loan.Loan_Id,Loan.CarriedForwardPayments,Payment.Amount,Loan.PaymentAmount;

Comment: It feels odd that I have added so many fields to the GROUP BY clause. Is this right?

Comment: See my edit and revised paragraph. Due to your expression, you need to use a subquery or domain aggregate, specifically `DSum`.

Comment: When I run the edited query the error message goes away but the calculation is no longer accurate. I am trying to troubleshoot the updated formula to determine where the calculation is off.